# C# Bot Framework for MS Teams- How to send an ad hoc proactive message as a new conversation

Tags: c#, botframework

Any help is appreciated, i tried below and its working inside Microsoft teams, it is sending a proactive message indeed to an existing conversation but i need a new conversation started with the message i send.

```
var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(toId,toName);
var botAccount = new ChannelAccount(fromId, fromName);
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(serviceUrl));

// Create a new message.
IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(conversationId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(channelId))  
{
    // If conversation ID and channel ID was stored previously, use it.
    message.ChannelId = channelId;
}
else
{
    // Conversation ID was not stored previously, so create a conversation. 
    // Note: If the user has an existing conversation in a channel, this will likely create a new conversation window.
    conversationId = (await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync( botAccount, userAccount)).Id;
}

// Set the address-related properties in the message and send the message.
message.From = botAccount;
message.Recipient = userAccount;
message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId);
message.Text = "Hello, this is a notification";
message.Locale = "en-us";
await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```

I tried below but it returns an error saying bad request

```
var channelData = new TeamsChannelData { Channel = new ChannelInfo(yourChannelId) };
IMessageActivity newMessage = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
newMessage.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
newMessage.Text = "Hello, on a new thread";
ConversationParameters conversationParams = new ConversationParameters(
    isGroup: true,
    bot: null,
    members: null,
    topicName: "Test Conversation",
    activity: (Activity)newMessage,
    channelData: channelData);
var result = await connector.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(conversationParams);
```

Comment: I have also tried this, without success. Please file an issue on the BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams repository: https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/issues